# How does Battlelog launch games from browser?

Tags: html, web-applications, game-development

[Battlelog](http://battlelog.battlefield.com) was released by EA alongside Battlefield 3 recently, and I'm curious how it is able to launch games, such as Battlefield 3, from a web browser?

More generally, how does a website launch programs locally?

Comment: Did you notice it asked you to install a plugin in the browser. I guess everything is handled by this plugin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm one of the developer responsible for the launch part of Battlelog. It's handled by a combination of the installed web browser plugin and JavaScript. Launching the game basically goes through these steps.

1. We figure out where you've installed the BF3.exe by using a registry key
2. We use the plugin to launch that exe with a couple of command line options
3. When the game client has launched, it opens a connection back to the plugin, for two-way communication between Battlelog and the game.
4. Game client sends state info and error messages back through the connection, so we can show progress and errors in Battlelog, and also know when the game has closed down.

Comment: How do you open a communication back to the plugin ? (If that's not too much to ask :P)

Comment: About the browser plugin: does this mean it's not compatible with Safari?

Comment: And what about the plugin-free launching that battlefield used afterwards? How does that work?

Answer (score 2):

It is thanks to the plugin you installed at battlelog.  Websites are not allowed to execute programs on your local machine due to the HUGE security risk that would present.  Plugins have to be used if you want to accomplish virtually anything outside the context of the browser, which is why you have to explicitly give them permission to install when they try to run.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are two options. First, the link points to a file which has an extension understandable only to that program, like when you click a .pdf link a pdf viewer will open. My second guess is that the link may use another protocol associated to the program in question, does the link start really with http://?

Comment: No, it doesn't start with http:// (I just added it so that the link would show up properly).  The actual site is battlelog.battlefield.com.

Comment: Ops, sorry. I meant if it started with another prefix. For instance donkey magnet links start with ed2k:// instead of http://

Answer (score 0):

Im almost 100% sure it uses the plugin you have to install to manage the launch process as it also controls whether the game is minimised or not.